# Testrun wont start in VS2019 correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, unit-testing

The message I get is:

Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von Executor "executor://nunit3testexecutor/": Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.IChannel' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Gaby

Comment: Your tests project has a missing dependency.

Comment: Could you change the framework for the project to the latest one to try?[Double click the Properties>Application tab>Target framework]

Comment: thanx for helping, we find another way, we don't use netcoreapp anymore, we only use .Net and framework 4.7.2, now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and clearing up the cache wouldn't do any good.
It appears if you have converted from legacy csproj format to SDK format, this problem might appear if you still have retained import statements. You may have to remove them and also delete bin and obj folder. After failing all attempts, only getting rid of imports and deleting the bin folder helped me run my .netcore3.1 tests.

Check here for more information,

https://githubmemory.com/repo/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/842